# error : binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [1]

Tags: c++

Mine is a simple c++ program to calculate area of circle, but I get this error.Can anyone help me? I'm new to c++. Here is my program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int area;
    float r;
    area = 3.14 * r * r;
    cin >> "enter the radius" >> r;
    cout << "Area of the circle is:" << area;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin>>"enter the radius">>r;` This is wrong. Do it like this: `cout << "enter the radius: ";  cin >> r;` Furthermore ask for radius before calculating the `area`.

Comment: I wonder why so many people seem to be afraid of using the space and tab keys on their keyboards...

Answer (score 3):

You can't read **in** to the literal `"enter the radius"`; this is what the compiler is telling you: it's attempting to write to the first element of that literal which is a `const char[1]` type.

You need to display that message to the user via `cout`, as you do when you're outputting the area. Then read in the radius using

```
cin >> r;
```

You also ought not evaluate `area` until `r` is known.

(By the way, your definition of `pi` is woeful for a `float` type: I tend to use `atan(1)*4` for `pi`; the C++ standard library does not define it for you.)

Comment: It's a pity pi isn't defined by the way. Including a `cmath` header and getting neither PI nor E really feels something's lacking. Your trick is nice, but it prevents using it for any kind of constexpr. Anyway.

Comment: #include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
 int area;
 float r;
 area = 3.14*r*r;
 cout << "enter the radius" << r;
 cin >> r;
 cout << "Area of the circle is:" << area;
 getchar();
 return 0;
}

Comment: @spectras: You can calculate PI using metaprogramming, based on this formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula. Then you can have it as a `constexpr`! But **please** don't put that into production!